# Anyone knows how to use mpandroidchart in kotlin Android latest

Tags: android, graph, charts, kotlin, mpandroidchart

I tried to use it but getting some commands missing. like they are available but not working with other commands like I watched them in java tutorials.

Answer (score 0):

Its working fine.... there wasn't any problem I just imported a wrong library from Dependencies, which looks exactly the same as mpAndroidchart.
Now I worked with the real one. It's amazing.......... :)